# How do you store the selected option from a dynamic drop down list

Tags: php, html, sql, dynamic, drop-down-menu

EDIT:

So, I have the color transferring to my cart page, but It is selecting the last option in my drop down when I try to add it to cart. I've been looking at ways to implement selected='selected', but it's a pain in this while loop.

My current products page:

```
        <?php
include("include/db.php");
include("include/productfunctions.php");

 if($_REQUEST['command'] == 'add' && $_REQUEST['productid'] > 0 &&   $_REQUEST['Color'] != ' ')
 {
    $product_id = $_REQUEST['productid'];
    $color = $_REQUEST['Color'];
    add_to_cart($product_id, 1, $color);
    header("Location:cart.php");
    exit();
 }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
//This js is necessary to determine which button on the 
// form the user clicked.

function addtocart(prod_id, color_ID)
{
document.productform.productid.value = prod_id;
document.productform.Color.value = color_ID;
document.productform.command.value = 'add';
document.productform.submit();
}
</script>

<form name="productform" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="Color" />
<input type="hidden" name="productid" />
<input type="hidden" name="command" />
</form>

<table id="product_table">
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM product";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("Error querying database");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $p_ID = $row['Prod_ID'];

    echo '
    <div class="img">
    <strong>'.$row['name'].'</strong>

    <br><img src="' . $row['image'] . '" /></br>

    <div class="desc"> 
    Description: ' . $row['description'] . '<br>        
    <br>Price: $ ' . $row['price'] . '</br>
    <br>
    </div>';
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM color c JOIN inventory i ON ( c.Color_ID =  i.Color_ID ) JOIN product p ON ( p.Prod_ID = i.Prod_ID ) WHERE p.Prod_ID = $p_ID"; 
    $result1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query1) or die("Error querying database");

    Print "<p>Decorative Color:\n";
    Print "<select name=\"Color_ID\">\n";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
    {
        $color_ID = $row['Color_ID'];

        Print "<option value=".$row['Color_ID']."> " . $row['Color'] . "\n     </option>";

    }

    Print "</select>\n";
    Print "</p>\n";

    echo '<div class="checkout">
    <input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart('. $p_ID .    ','. $color_ID . ')" /></br>
    </div>
    </div>';

} 

?>

</table>
```

function to add to cart:

```
    function add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $color)
{
if($product_id < 1 || $quantity < 1)
{
    return;
}

if(is_array($_SESSION['cart']))
{
    $exists_results = product_exists($product_id);
    $exists = $exists_results[0];
    $position = $exists_results[1];

    if($exists)
    {
        $new_quantity = intval($_SESSION['cart'][$position]['quantity']);
        $new_quantity++;
        $_SESSION['cart'][$position]['quantity'] = $new_quantity;
    }
    else
    {
        $max = count($_SESSION['cart']);
        $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['productid'] = $product_id;
        $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['quantity'] = $quantity;
        $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['Color'] = $color;
    }

}

else
{
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
    $_SESSION['cart'][0]['productid'] = $product_id;
    $_SESSION['cart'][0]['quantity'] = $quantity;
    $_SESSION['cart'][0]['Color'] = $color;
}
}



 function product_exists($product_id)
{
$product_id = intval($product_id);
$max = count($_SESSION['cart']);
$flag = 0;

for($i=0; $i < $max; $i++)
{
        if($product_id == $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'])
        {
            $flag = 1;
            break;
        }
}
return array ($flag, $i);
}

?>
```

The cart:

```
<?php
if(count($_SESSION['cart']))
{
    echo '<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Decorative Color</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Options</th>
    </tr>';

    $max = count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
    {
        $product_id = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $quantity = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['quantity'];
        $color = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['Color'];
        $product_name = get_product_name($dbc, $product_id);
        $product_price = get_price($dbc, $product_id);
        $product_color = get_color($dbc, $color);

        if($quantity == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        echo '<tr>
        <td>' . $product_name . '</td>
        <td>&#36; ' . $product_price . '</td>
        <td>' . $product_color . '</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="product' . $product_id . '" value="' .
                        $quantity . '" maxlength="4"   size="2" /></td>
        <td>&#36; ' . $product_price*$quantity . '</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:del(' . $product_id . ')">Remove Item</a>   </td>
        </tr>';         
    }

    echo '<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><strong>Order Total: &#36;' . get_order_total($dbc) .   '</strong></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="cart_buttons">
    <input type="submit" value="Clear Cart" onclick="clear_cart()">
    <input type="submit" value="Update Cart" onclick="update_cart()">
    <input type="submit" value="Complete Order" onclick="complete_order()">
    </td>
    </tr>';
}
else
{
    echo '<tr><td>There are no items in your shopping cart.</td></tr>';
}
?>
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
function addtocart(prod_id)
{
document.productform.productid.value = prod_id;
document.productform.Color.value = $("select[name='color_' + prod_id] option:selected").val();
document.productform.command.value = 'add';
document.productform.submit();
}
```

Other Edit:

```
Print "<select name=\"Color_" . $p_ID . "\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my observations will help, just some things I noticed or wondered about. In the first code block, it seems that you didn't provide closing option tags.

And in the second code block, I see that you try to GET the color, but then it doesn't look like you do anything with it. Also, you are doing a GET on "color" but the name of the select for Decorative Colors is "Color_ID". Finally, you seem to have put a blank cell where the item's "Decorative Color" is presumably supposed to appear. Can you confirm whether those details were intentional or not?

**Edit:** Add the following line to your <head>, before all other JS, to import jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

In your addtocart function, remove the color as the argument. Instead, change the document.productform.Color.value line to the following.

```
document.productform.Color.value = $("select[name='Color_ID']").val();
```

Something like that should work, but you'll have to try it. So let's dissect the $("select[name='Color_ID']").val() part of the line. In jQuery, you can select certain elements or groups of elements from the DOM; $("p") would select all paragraph elements, $("a") would select all anchor elements, and these are called selectors.

And you can specify further by saying you want elements with certain attributes; in this case, you are getting any selects with the name attribute "Color_ID" with the "[name='Color_ID']" part appended to the "select" element. After grabbing that particular element, the val() function on any selector is going to grab the selected element's value. See if that works.

**Edit 2:**

```
document.productform.Color.value = $("select[name='Color_ID'] option:selected").val();
```

**Edit 3:**

```
document.productform.Color.value = $("select[name='color_' + prod_id +] option:selected").val();
```

In this case, for each select, you'll have to give it the name "color_" . $p_ID. It just  depends on however you want to name it.

Comment: Ya I had $color in that cell where it would appear but its not transferring. I also changed the GET to Color_ID and that isn't transferring the value either.

Comment: Did you also end up closing the option tags? Either way, I think it might be important to see what happens during the addtocart function, since I don't know how you were trying to transfer the data to the cart.

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery? In your addtocart JS function, using jQuery, you can select "select[name='Color_ID']" and get its current value.

Comment: I haven't used jQuery before. Could you show me an example of how I could use it in my code?

Comment: I implemented what you said, and when I add products to the cart it is transferring the color of the very first option for my first product for any of the products that I try to add to cart.

Comment: Ahh, it works effectively for the first product, but if I add any other product to my cart it will add the product to the cart with the color that was selected for the first product.

Comment: You'd have to make the select unique to each product. They're all named "Color_ID", but perhaps you should name them uniquely based on the product ID or something. In that case, you should also change the selector for the selects. I'll add another edit to show you what you might want to try.

Comment: Ya this is working great for the first product. If I go to add any of the other product on my cart it displays 'pink' which is the very first option for color for my first product.

Comment: Even if you differentiate between each select with different names? This difference has to take place in both your JS function and the PHP loop where you write all the information about each product.

Comment: In my original posts, is the edits I believe you were saying. Is that correct?

Comment: Okay, I see you were trying to follow my suggestion, but that's not exactly right. You print "<select name=\"Color_" . $p_ID . "\">", but your selector is $("select[name='color_ID' + color] option:selected"). It's not selecting the right thing, since the name is in the format "Color_[product_id]". The selector should be $("select[name='Color_' + prod_id] option:selected").

Comment: Ya I just realized that I had the wrong selector, and I changed it to that. Unfortunately, I'm getting the same thing. I changed it in my original post.